# How run wkhtmltopdf(.exe) installed as NuGet package in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, wkhtmltopdf

I am using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in my C#.NET project to convert html to pdf.
I've added the executable in my project, I can reference it and run it and everything works fine.

The executable is also available as [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/wkhtmltopdf-x86-win32/) so I've decided to download the package in Visual Studio. 
The question is how can I run the executable now? In general, all Nuget packages that contain executable how can be referenced in the project in order to run them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable is in the Bin folder, so the path just need to change to that folder